# React IonSlide right left navigation not woriking

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionslider

Hi I am using ionic react. I tried ionslide and its working fine with the slide /swap. But I can't manage to show slider right left navigation. And my pagination dot works fine.
I cant even find a way to use custom slide next prev button.

How to use **slideNext** from the documentation.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides#methods

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to get a way around. here is the solution if anyone interested.
first get an instance and set a state.

```
  const [swiper, setSwiper] = useState<any>({});
  const init = async function(this: any) {
    setSwiper(await this.getSwiper());
};
<IonSlides options={slideOpts} mode="ios"  onIonSlidesDidLoad={init}  >
```

after that on my next button handler

```
  const handleSlidesControlNext = () =>{
      swiper.slideNext(300)
  }
```